# Is there a way to any operation that set `Observable<Unit>` without using `map{ }`

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have a `isTextSetSignal` that will be set true when some text is set. Only when a text is set then I need my keyboard hide. So I have another a `hideKeyboardSignal` that will be triggered whenever keyboard is set.

I wrote it as below, and it works.

```
val hideKeyboardSignal: Observable<Unit> = isTextSetSignal.filter{ it }.map {  }
```

I just wonder if there's a better way of doing so, wither not using `Unit` or not `map{  }`, as they look hacky?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no external need to have a `Unit`, you can replace `Unit` by `*`.
Then you can shortcut to this.

```
val hideKeyboardSignal: Observable<*> = isTextSetSignal.filter{ it }
```

This preserves the Boolean objects, not sure if that is working out with `rx-java`.